# multiple highlight with multiple color

Tags: search, highlight

When we search for a word, it gets highlighted.

I want to search for another word keeping the previous one highlighted (with a different color probably).

Please let me know if it's doable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/704434/is-there-any-way-to-highlight-multiple-searches-in-gvim